# System command to mail text output

Tags: file-io, ibm-midrange, cl

AS400 CLLE SQL

How can i create program which will count no of active subsystem in wrksbs command and give the output on mail text(not attachment) in clle as400? How to run system command in clle program n take output rather than *print

I tried using sql, pf,

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier in a different language like RPG or Python, because those languages have direct support for putting SQL results into variables, but it can be done indirectly in CL. The idea is to use RUNSQL to create a temporary table and then use the [IBM i service QSYS2.SUBSYSTEM_INFO](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-subsystem-info-view) to count the active subsystems and place the result into that table. Then read the table into a CL variable and send it in an email.

Note that before this will compile you will need to create the table into QTEMP; copy/paste the RUNSQL command into your command line before compiling.

Tested on IBM i 7.4

```
/* Email subsystem info */
pgm

/* this file needs to exist before compiling this CLP */
dclf sbsinf opnid(sbsinf)

dcl &toEmail *char 64
dcl &intChar *char 10
dcl &msg *char 64

/* create a temporary file to hold the results */
dltf qtemp/sbsinf
monmsg cpf2105

runsql 'create table qtemp.sbsinf +
  (sbscount integer)' +
  commit(*none) naming(*sql)

/* use SQL services to populate the temp file */
runsql ('insert into qtemp.sbsinf +
  (sbscount) (select count(*) +
   from qsys2.subsystem_info +
   where status = ''ACTIVE'')') +
  commit(*none) naming(*sql)

/* read the temp file into a variable */
ovrdbf sbsinf qtemp/sbsinf
rcvf rcdfmt(sbsinf) opnid(sbsinf)
monmsg cpf0864 exec(goto eof)

/* build the message text */
chgvar &intChar &sbsinf_sbscount
chgvar &msg (&intChar *bcat 'active subsystems')

/* Email the results */
chgvar &toEmail 'your.email@goes.here'
sndsmtpemm rcp((&toEmail)) +
  subject('Active subsystem count') +
  note(&msg)

/* clean up and leave */
eof:

endpgm
```